# Python: How to correctly use external functions

Tags: python, class, function, import, pyqt

This is something I've seen a fair bit of documentation on but I can't get an exact answer to this specific gap in my knowledge and I keep running into walls because of it, nothing seems to really cover it on this level:

I have a few windows, all of them should be draggable, so I'm building a utilities file. In this file I have this:

```
def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    if self.moving: self.move(event.globalPos()-self.offset)

def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
        self.moving = True; self.offset = event.pos()


def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
    if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
        self.moving = False
```

And this will work if I put it into a single file (and don't call from another one) with the actual window.

The question is, how do I call to this from another file (the one that has the UI window)?

I am calling to it by

```
 from utils import *
```

So technically those functions are all accessible simply by typing

```
mouseReleaseEvent(x,x)
```

But I need the UI to import those functions, so in the main file after putting up the 'from utils import *' I type:

```
self.moving = False
```

But that errors no matter what I do. So the question is what is the proper way to enclose the functions listed first (first code block) so that I can call to them from within my UI file?

Here is my UI code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

    import sys
    import os
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
    from vibotCss import css
    from viUtils import *

    class viBadOSUI(QtGui.QDialog):
        def __init__(self):
            QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
            #setup window
            self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
            self.resize(300, 150)
            center(self)
            self.setMouseTracking(True)



            #additional code
            self.show()
            self.setStyleSheet(css)



    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = viBadOSUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have large gaps in my Python knowledge due to learning and using it solely from within Autodesk Maya for a long time - I am trying to bridge said gaps now. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are looking for are mixins:

For example, in **viUtils.py** you could define:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Draggable(object):
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        try:
            if self.moving:
                self.move(event.globalPos()-self.offset)
        except AttributeError:
            pass

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.moving = True; self.offset = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):   
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.moving = False

class Centerable(object):
    pass # add code here

class CountdownTimer(object):
    pass # add code here
```

By bundling related methods together in mixins, you can add functionality to your classes (windows) by simply adding the mixin(s) to the base classes:

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from vibotCss import css
import viUtils

class viBadOSUI(QtGui.QDialog, 
                viUtils.Draggable, viUtils.CountdownTimer):

    def __init__(self):            
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        #setup window
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.resize(300, 150)
        center(self)  # You should probably make `center` a method instead of a function and call `self.center()` instead.
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

        #additional code
        self.show()
        self.setStyleSheet(css)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = viBadOSUI()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

One thing I do not like about my code above is that I could not figure out how to define a mixin (e.g. `Draggable`) with an `__init__` which gets called automatically by `viBadOSUI.__init__`. Normally you would use `super` for this, but it appears `QtGui.QDialog.__init__` does not itself call `super`.

(Actually, I think it might be possible to use `super` **if** you put the mixins **before** `QtGui.QDialog`, but this relies on trickery which will break once someone forgets that `QtGui.QDialog` must appear last in the list of bases.)

Because I could not define an `__init__` method which would work robustly:

```
class Draggable(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.moving = False
```

I instead modified `mouseMoveEvent` to use a `try..except`. 
This is better than adding `self.moving = False` directly to `viBadOSUI.__init__` because this attribute is used only by Draggable, and therefore should be somehow bundled with `Draggable`. Setting the mixin and then **also** having to remember to initialize an attribute just so the mixin will work is ugly programming.

Using `try..except` here is perhaps slightly better than using `if hasattr(self, 'moving')` since the try is quicker as long as an exception is not raised, and the exception will be raised only at the beginning before the first mousePressEvent.

Still, there is room for improvement and I hope someone here will show us a better way.

An alternative approach would have been to define

```
class viBadOSUI(QtGui.QDialog):
    mouseMoveEvent = viUtils.mouseMoveEvent
    mousePressEvent = viUtils.mousePressEvent
    mouseReleaseEvent = viUtils.mouseReleaseEvent
```

This gives you a lot of flexibility to add exactly those methods you want from viUtils directly into any class you define. However, I think it is a bit too much flexibility since mouseMoveEvent, mousePressEvent, and mouseReleaseEvent seem "bundled" to me. They all work together to implement a single piece of functionality. This is why I like the mixin approach better. Also, adding `viUtils.Draggable` to the base classes is less typing than adding those 3 lines to every window subclass that you want to be draggable.

By the way, I'd recommend eschewing `from viUtils import *` and using `import viUtils` instead. It will keep your code more organized in the long run.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for taking the time to respond. I'm actually still quite lost, but I did as you said and the resulting error was: RuntimeError: underlying C/C++ object has been deleted - this occurs due to the line 'viUtils.viDragUI.__init__(self)' presumably.

Comment: I tested the code I posted. I works (if you comment out the `center(self)` and `self.setStyleSheet(css)` -- I assumed you defined these elsewhere). So I'm not sure why you are encountering a `RuntimeError`. The error must be due to other code which has not been posted! :)

Comment: Hi there, the problem comes from `window = viBadOSUI()` says the interpreter. I have commented out EVERYTHING possible and still the code wont run, complaining about that. There's another thing; I don't really like this method and don't understand why I should use it, because if I want to use multiple functions from within my viUtils.py file, I can't call all of them this way, and it also seems very messy, there really has to be a proper way to do it[?] Not to say I don't appreciate your help, I do, but this way doesn't feel right.

Comment: If you post code that I can run to reproduce the error, I'll take a look -- no promises I can find it though. Regarding your larger question (why use this approach): can you elaborate on why "if I want to use multiple functions from within my viUtils.py file, I can't call all of them this way"? Can you give an example?

Comment: I don't have access to the hdd with the code right at this moment but to answer the second part, if I want to make every window draggable, or center on the screen, I don't want to copy paste that code all through the app, it's too messy, I want a viUtils.py file that contains the repeatedly used methods and call to the file when needed. A more specific example is I could need to use the method to center a window, to make draggable, and maybe all my windows have an countdown timer on them, the point is that this method doesn't give me access to my own functions if I require more than one.

Answer (score 2):

The `self` (first) argument on a method refers to the instance on which it is bound. The equivalent of `self.moving = False` outside a method is to bind `False` to the `moving` attribute of an instance, e.g. `obj.moving = False`.

Comment: Not to be rude but you pretty much reworded my question without providing an answer. I'll gladly listen if you have a solution :)